# Using isset and filter_input the correct way in PHP

Tags: php, isset, superglobals

I am developing a basic API for some simple functionality. I am capturing inputs like below:

```
if ($action == 'delete' && isset($_POST['targetId']) && isset($_POST['userId'])) {
//The isset causes "Do not access Superglobal _POST array directly" warning in Netbeans
        $userId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userId');
        $beamId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'targetId');
}
```

Should I use filter_input even for checking whether the value is set? Like:

```
if ($action == 'delete' && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'targetId') && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userId')) {

}
```

I am not looking at options here rather I would be happy with the most correct solution which is  secure and hack resistant.

EDIT: Yes, the above information will be used as inputs for SQL

Comment: Are you gonna use the provided user data in SQL statements later? If so,  then the most secure way is to use **prepared** SQL statements.

Comment: Yes, I will be using the values as input for constructing SQL statements.

Comment: OK, then learn how to use PHP PDO (PHP Data Objects) as good practice: https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I am using PDO for all SQL related things in the API. Thanks for the heads up though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter_input` is used to sanitize or check the data type of the input. It is used to make sure that the data you are expecting is in the required format and you can sanitize it using required filters. `isset` in your case will check if the required variable is set or not (or is not NULL). So both have different usecases. I don't see using `isset` directly on a POST item as bad but I would recommend using `filter_input` so that the data can be validated as well.

Comment: So using isset initially to check whether the value has been set and then using filter_input to verify if the right data is set. Is this the recommended way?

Comment: yeah that is one way of using it.

Comment: **If the flag FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is used, it returns FALSE if the variable is not set**

Answer (score 8):

Another solution could be use filter_has_var().

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "userId")) {
    //occurs when $_POST['userId'] is set, even when empty
}
```

More info in: [Official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-has-var.php)

Comment: You can also see the official documentation in http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-has-var.php

Comment: @PhoneixS You´re right, better link to the Official Doc instead of w3schools. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with unfiltered input is essentially code injection. That's a problem where you use the input as part of a SQL statement or your output back to the user (JavaScript).

As such, it is not necessary to do it just to check if a value was entered. It is good to rather be consistent and use `filter_input` first to populate variables and then use those variables to check if the fields were populated if you will be using the value as above later on in your script.